# Swift: compiler is giving a weird error when using generics and a property wrapper

Tags: swift, generics

I am running into a Swift issue that I don't really understand.

Consider this code (you can paste this into a playground):

```swift
import UIKit

protocol Selectable: Equatable {
  var label: String { get }
}

enum Gender: String, CaseIterable, Equatable, Selectable {
  case male
  case female

  var label: String {
    return rawValue.capitalized
  }
}

protocol Delegate: class {
  func openSelectionScreen<Option: Selectable>(title: String, options: [Option], selectedOption: Option?, selectionChanged: @escaping (Option) -> Void)
}

class Test {
  weak var delegate: Delegate?
  @Published var selectedGender = Gender.male

  init() {
    delegate?.openSelectionScreen(title: "Gender", options: Gender.allCases, selectedOption: selectedGender) { option in
      self.selectedGender = option
    }
  }
}
```

This gives a compiler error `Cannot assign value of type '_' to type 'Gender'`. It doesn't happen when I remove the `@Published` wrapper from the `selectedGender` variable. And the error also goes away if I do this:

```swift
delegate?.openSelectionScreen(title: "Gender", options: Gender.allCases, selectedOption: selectedGender.self) { option in
  self.selectedGender = option
}
```

Notice the use of `.self` after `selectedGender`.

So, I have a workaround, the code works as expected. But.. why is this happening? And since `selectedGender` and `selectedGender.self` have the same type (`Gender`), why does one version work and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a Swift's type inference and type checking issue. In some cases, the complex expression, type constraints cause these kind of issue.

`@Publisher` annotation is root cause in this case. In the function call, it doesn't recognise the `selectedGender` has Gender type.

You can fix it by do the type cast:

```
delegate?.openSelectionScreen(title: "Gender", options: Gender.allCases, selectedOption: selectedGender as Gender?) { option in
      self.selectedGender = option
}
```